# Rheem 96V gas furnace with error code 61, then code 22. Blower error and high limit error

Tags: hvac

For the past few weeks I've had intermittent problems with my heat furnace.  It looks like the blower motor was not always turning on and now it's flashing code 61.  It would ignite and I can see on the control board of my Honeywell that it's calling for zone heat but still no blower action consistently. Do I need a new blower motor?  How do I diagnose the issue?

A few days after I installed a nest thermostat (where I swapped the G fan wire into a common wire and left the fan wire out) I started to notice the furnace wasn't always turning on when it called for heat.  I thought maybe it was the nest thermostat (we already had another nest thermostat with the power connector adapter from before with no problems) so I added a NEST power connector to add a wire for the C, but that didn't seem to make a difference so maybe it's only coincidence that it started to act on the fritz after the thermostat.

How would I know if the Nest thermostat would cause any of these issues?

Restarting the system would have the blower turn on with heat, but it was not consistent and would not blow hot air for long stretches of time.  It ran for an hour today after I rebooted it but stopped again.

Error code 0 on restart, but after we call for heat, it sounds like it ignites, but then the blower doesn't turn on and it flashes error code 61.  After a while it flashes error code 22.

How do I diagnose?

Also of note, there is a large bypass flapper that I weighed down a bit more since it always opened regardless of pressure when all zones were on.  Could that have worn down the motor this quickly?

Link to [Manual](https://cdn.globalimageserver.com/FetchDocument.aspx?ID=C4240D50-5435-4433-91BD-A6BB8111BEFD)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Since the first thing I would check is the new thermostat. Put the old back and see if the problem resolves itself. If not you know where the problem is, fix that first as that setup was known good then put the new thermostat back.

Comment: it didn't work with the old thermostat either - ended up replacing the motor